# Is there any way to know if a file is being opened by the user?

Tags: node.js, npm, cross-platform, electron, file-watcher

My question is simple. I am creating an electron app using Node JS to watch a particular directory. I would like to know is there any way, like a file watcher or something else that could tell me if a file being opened by the user?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "being opened"? What is your use case?

Comment: @ralphtheninja Being opened in my case is, knowing that a user just opened a file.

Comment: Sure, but opened how?

Comment: @ralphtheninja By clicking on the file and opening it using default program. For example, a user clicks on a video file and it's being opened in VLC. I hope that explains. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can notice if someone renames or changes a file using `fs.watch` etc but that's it.